# Ruby and Enterprise Architect

Tags: ruby, types, configuration, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to build a class diagram in [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) for future usage in Ruby project.

How should I set up base [code datatypes](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/uml_model_management/datatypes.html) (*Settings -> Code Datatypes...*)?

It should be something like: *Datatype = Common Type (additional notes, if any)*. Does anyone know what pairs should be input?

I'd also highly appreciate advice on how to import the whole ruby/rails library into Sparx.

**Update 1**: added links to resources. It's also stated [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/code_engineering/reverseengineersourcecode.html), that they don't support reverse engineering of ruby code. So, can anyone suggest a different tool for my case?

Many thanks!

**Update 2**: there is actually [one that I've found](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-uml/), but it's quite out of date. Any other ideas?

Comment: It might help if you provide some information about what the heck a "Sparx Enterprise Architect" or a "base code datatype" or a "Common Type" is and how that relates to Ruby.

Comment: It's a UML modeling tool. I've updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: Ruby is dynamically typed so the only type is Ducktype!

Comment: What is your intention with EA? Do you just want to have a documentation / overview of what you programmed with ruby? Or do you want to use EA for "forward engineering" e.g. generate ruby code from your diagrams? Or even "roundtrip" engineering?

Comment: Roundtrip would be excellent, however I was only looking for "forward" solution.